# How to animate text with jquery to slide to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I keep track of right and wrong answers and I want to slide the text from the right of the screen.

Here is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```js
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Number of Right Answers: " + right;
document.getElementById('totalw').innerHTML = "Number of Wrong Answers: " + wrong;
$("#total").show("slide", {
  direction: "right"
}, 2000);
$("#totalw").show("slide", {
  direction: "right"
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="total"></div>
<div id="totalw"></div>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what's going on... could you provide a working jsfiddle demonstrating the issue?

I'm going to guess based on your js that you want these two elements (previously hidden) to fade in with .show()? What exactly is not working? Are they not displaying? Are they not sliding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in file html:

```js
$('#total').html("Number of Right Answers: " + "right");
$('#totalw').html("Number of Wrong Answers: " + "wrong");
$("#total").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
$("#totalw").show( "slide", {direction: "right" }, 2000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
<div id="total"></div>
<div id="totalw"></div>
```

Comment: What exactly was the solution? Was jQuery not included?

Comment: yes :) [jquery.effects.core.js, jquery.effects.slide]